# A contradiction in Panjer recursion formula

Tags: probability

I am afraid I have found a contradiction in Panjer recursion formula.
First, assume that $N\sim NB(1,\frac{1}{2})$. It means that N has negative binomial distribution which in this case is geometric distribution. Assume also that $X_i$ have uniform distribution on $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and all are i.i.d.
Consider $S_N=X_1+...+X_N$. First we compute $P(S_N=0)$.
By the law of total probability:
$$P(S_{N}=0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(S_n=0)P(N=n)=$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(X=0)(1-p)^{n-1}p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{4})^{n}(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{7}$$
Now lets calculate $P(S_{N}=1)$

$$P(S_{N}=1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(S_n=1)P(N=n)=$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP(X_1=1)P(X_2=0,...,X_{n-1}=0)(1-p)^{n-1}p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(\frac{1}{4})^{n}(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}\frac{1}{2}=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(\frac{1}{8})^{n}=\frac{8}{49}$$

Now calculate the same using Panjer recursion formula. We start with $P(S_N=0)=\frac{1}{7}$

Panjer recursion formula states that

$$P(S_N=k)=\frac{1}{1-ag_0}\sum_{i=1}^k(a+\frac{bi}{k})g_iP(S_N=k-i)$$

$g_k$ is simply distribution of $X$

In the case of negative binomial we have consecutively

$$a=1-p=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$b=(r-1)(1-p)=0$$
$$g_k=\frac{1}{4},\quad k=1,2,3,4$$
$$g_k=0,\quad k>4$$

And finally lets compute $P(S_N=1)$ using Panjer recursion formula in our case

$$P(S_N=1)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{8}}\sum_{i=1}^1\frac{1}{8}P(S_N=1-i)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{8}}\frac{1}{8}P(S_N=0)=\frac{1}{49}$$

But, by the direct computation I obtained $P(S_N=1)=\frac{8}{49}$

I am looking for contradiction in my reasoning for hours but I cannot find...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Panjer formula works fine when the support of negative binomial is nonnegative integers, instead of positive integers.